# Why does Bootstrap override my CSS definition for a non Bootstrap id?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>MyApp</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css">
      <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app.css">
    </head>

    <body>
    <section class="sect-break" id="home-top-container">
        <div class="cell-display">
          <div class="title divInside"><h1>WELCOME!</h1></div>
          <div class="divInside" id="tagline"><h2><i>tagline</i></h2></div>

          <div class="divInside"><h1>WHAT?</h1></div>
          <div class="divInside"><h2><p>Part 1
         <p>Part 2
<p>Part 3</p></h2></div>
        </div>
    </section>
      <section id="problem">
        <div class="title"><h1>WHY?</h1></div>
        <div class="container problem-top-level">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 flex j-c-s-between a-i-center">
              <div class="problem-container">
                <div class="flex j-c-center a-i-center"><div class="problem-circle flex j-c-center a-i-center"><i class="fa fa-4x fa-group"></i></div></div>
                <h3>Problem!</h3>
                <p>Reason</p>
              </div>
              <div class="problem-container">
                <div class="flex j-c-center a-i-center"><div class="problem-circle flex j-c-center a-i-center"><i class="fa fa-4x fa-ticket"></i></div></div>
                <h3>Problem!</h3>
                <p>Reason</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      </section>

      <section id="solution-header" class="sect-break flex a-i-center">
        <div class="m-l-lg title"><h1>Solution</h1></div>    
      </section>

      <section id="solution">
        <div class="container problem-top-level">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 flex j-c-s-between a-i-center">
              <div class="problem-container">
                <div class="flex j-c-center a-i-center"><div class="solution-circle flex j-c-center a-i-center"><i class="fa fa-4x fa-glass"></i></div></div>
                <h3>Solution</h3>
                <p>Reason</p>
              </div>
              <div class="problem-container">
                <div class="flex j-c-center a-i-center"><div class="solution-circle flex j-c-center a-i-center"><i class="fa fa-4x fa-home"></i></div></div>
                <h3>Solution</h3>
                <p>Reason</p>
              </div>
              <div class="problem-container">
                <div class="flex j-c-center a-i-center"><div class="solution-circle flex j-c-center a-i-center"><i class="fa fa-4x fa-percent"></i></div></div>
                <h3>Solution</h3>
                <p>Reason</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
      </section>
      <section id="contact" class="sect-break">
        <h1>Interested? <a href="email.address">Contact us</a></h1>
      </section>

      <script type="text/javascript" src="bundle.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

This is my head in my HTML and when I inspect the page with Chrome's inspection tools, I see `<style>` tags that hold most of my CSS, but the `id` I have modified to `height: 100vh` and in the `<style>` tags, it's `height: 300px`. I cannot for the life of me figure out where this is coming from and what is overriding me. Any ideas?

This is how I define `#problem` in app.css:

```
#problem {
  background-color: #0eaca7;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

And I do not have any inline `<style>` tags at all. When the page is loaded client-side, `<style>` tags appear in the head, perhaps generated by loading the CSS stylesheets? I'm new to web dev so I'm not actually sure where they come from.

This is what Chrome shows in inspection:
[image: chrome inspection tool showing difference between id's.]

Comment: Can you show us the actual markup? The `#problem` element and every inline `style` elements would be useful to help you.

Comment: @lexith Edited. Hopefully that's what you needed. I can't figure out where this other `#problem` definition is coming from.

Comment: Without the rest of your markup it's hard to help you.

Comment: @lexith I randomly filled in all the text, but that's the markup.

Comment: what's `bundle.js` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a selector with a higher specificity.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Like this:

```
body > section#problem {
  background-color: #0eaca7;
  height: 100vh;
}
```